# Capture response information from (3rd party) web service on error

Tags: c#, web-services, error-handling

I have the following code, which submits XML to a 3rd party web service, which errors (intentionally, at the moment) on "req.GetResponse()" with the error, detailed below.

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myXMLData);
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myWebsite);
using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
string responseStream = StringFromResponseStream(response);
```

Error from GetResponse()

**Exception thrown: 'System.New.WebExtension' in System.dll
Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request**

When I trace this call in Fiddler, I can see that the response from the service, also includes a far more useful error (below; RAW view), which I am trying to get to:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 16 Jun 2016 10:42:26 GMT
Cache-Control: private
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 54
Caseprovider-Credentials: <snip>
Caseprovider-Credentialshash: <snip>
Caseprovider-Apiversion: 15
Connection: close

No supported action 'SomeName' available for 'SomeValue'
```

Having a 'watch' on the variables doesn't seem to show where I might obtain this from (and quite possibly something simple that I have overlooked)

Answer (score 0):

Have eventually found a resolution for the; where 'result' contains the content from the process; there's more to do, but this is the basics of what I needed.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(myWebSite);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));

    StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(myXMLData);
    stringContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync(httpClient.BaseAddress, stringContent).Result;

    string result = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```